# how to make a wall ( boxGeometry ) hard so that the object cannot go through in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made a 3D maze use threejs to build, I using BoxGeometry to build a wall that the object can't cross. I tried to research and know that we need collision. So the problem is how to make an object can not go through the wall. ( I tried to use RayCaster or Cannon.js but it seems not working ). Here some code about build Geometry: ( the car was the object that I watch Wael Yasmina )

```
const box1Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 5);
const box1Material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color:999999});
const box1 = new THREE.Mesh(box1Geometry, box1Material);
box1.position.set(0, 2.5, 24.5);
scene.add(box1);

const box2Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 5);
const box2Material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color:999999});
const box2 = new THREE.Mesh(box2Geometry, box2Material);
box2.position.set(0, 2.5, -24.5);
scene.add(box2);

const box3Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 5, 49.5);
const box3Material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color:999999});
const box3 = new THREE.Mesh(box3Geometry, box3Material);
box3.position.set(50, 2.5, 0);
scene.add(box3);

const box4Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 5, 49.5);
const box4Material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color:999999});
const box4 = new THREE.Mesh(box4Geometry, box4Material);
box4.position.set(-49.5, 2.5, 0);
scene.add(box4);

const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 50);
const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
scene.add(plane);
plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
plane.receiveShadow = true;

const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 40);
scene.add(gridHelper);

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333);
scene.add(ambientLight);

const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF);
scene.add(spotLight);
spotLight.position.set(-100, 100, 0);
spotLight.castShadow = true;
spotLight.angle = 0.2;
 
const dLightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(spotLight);
scene.add(dLightHelper); 

scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0xFFFFFF, 0.01);

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 87){
        car.position.z += 1;
        car.rotation.y = 0
    } else if (e.keyCode === 83){
        car.position.z -= 1;
        car.rotation.y = 59.5;
    } else if (e.keyCode === 65){
        car.position.x += 1;
        car.rotation.y = -80 ;
    } else if (e.keyCode === 68){
        car.position.x -= 1;
        car.rotation.y = 80;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use a physics library for collision detection.
Physics libraries include:

- **Cannon**: https://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js
- **Rapier**: https://rapier.rs
- **Ammo**: https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js

For body collision, you will need to set the body type to static and use a kinematic character controller.